# why I am not getting all records from left table with LEFT JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql

I am running two Mysql queries 2nd one is not fetching all the records from Left table.

Table One -> audit_form_tbl

```
field id       company_form_id      field_name
1...................42..................A         
2................. 42...................b
3................. 42...................t
4................. 42...................bgf
5................. 42...................bfddf
```

Table Two -> audit_form_value_4_tbl

```
id             field id          company_form_id      field_name
1.................1................. 42................45
2.................3................. 42................50
3.................2................. 42................70
```

```
  SELECT aft.field_id, 
         aft.sort_order, 
         aft.type, 
         aft.parent_id, 
         aft.type, 
         aft.field_name 
  FROM audit_form_tbl aft 
  WHERE aft.type='FH' 
    AND aft.company_id = '4' 
    AND aft.company_form_id = '42' 
    AND aft.parent_id = '0' 
    AND aft.status = 1 
  ORDER BY sort_order
```

```
  SELECT aft.field_id, 
         aft.sort_order, 
         aft.type, 
         aft.parent_id, 
         aft.type, 
         aft.field_name 
         avt.field_value, 
  FROM audit_form_tbl aft 
  LEFT JOIN audit_form_value_4_tbl avt ON aft.field_id=avt.field_id 
  WHERE aft.type='FH' 
    AND aft.company_id = '4' 
    AND aft.company_form_id = '42' 
    AND aft.parent_id = '0' 
    AND aft.status = 1 
    AND avt.form_id='4421579691865' 
  ORDER BY sort_order
```

I want all the records from table one and matched records from table two.

Thanks

Comment: which table is audit_form_tbl and which is audit_form_value_4_tbl? Second query is not valid you have a comma after  avt.field_value and before the from

Comment: Can you please provide http://sqlfiddle.com/ for your case, that way it is easier for everyone to help you

Comment: @P.Salmon , please check i updated

Comment: You haven't fixed the second query , and the left join on is incorrectly formed.

Comment: @P.Salmon 2nd table is audit_form_value_4_tbl

Comment: You use a condition by right table  in WHERE - this converts your LEFT join to INNER join. Move the condition `AND avt.form_id='4421579691865'` from WHERE to ON.

Comment: @SuperMario'sYoshi Hi Mario, I am not aware of sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @Akina form_id does not store in audit_form_tbl , its in audit_form_value_4_tbl only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT aft.field_id, 
         aft.sort_order, 
         aft.type, 
         aft.parent_id, 
         aft.type, 
         aft.field_name 
         avt.field_value, 
  FROM audit_form_tbl aft 
  LEFT JOIN audit_form_value_4_tbl avt ON aft.field_id=avt.field_id 
                            -- insert the condition by right table to ON
                                      AND avt.form_id='4421579691865' 
  WHERE aft.type='FH' 
    AND aft.company_id = '4' 
    AND aft.company_form_id = '42' 
    AND aft.parent_id = '0' 
    AND aft.status = 1 
  -- remove the condition by right table from WHERE 
  --  AND avt.form_id='4421579691865' 
  ORDER BY sort_order
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `avt.form_id = '4421579691865'` in your `WHERE` clause. When there's no matching row to join, then `avt.form_id` is `NULL` and `avt.form_id = '4421579691865'` isn't true, hence the row gets filtered out. Move it to the `ON` clause.

```
...
LEFT JOIN audit_form_value_4_tbl avt
          ON aft.field_id = avt.field_id
             AND avt.form_id = '4421579691865'
...
```